# Are you familiar with the term "air-conditioningitis"?

Tags: vocabulary, is-it-a-word

According to [this article](http://www.koreaherald.com/view.php?ud=20110714000782), "[a]ir-conditioningitis occurs when the body cannot adjust properly to the sharp differences in temperature between the cool air-conditioned indoors and the warm outdoors."

But I've never heard any native speaker use this term or any other term even remotely related to this sort of "disease". How familiar are you, as a native speaker, with this term or this type of disease itself?

Is this something you'd consider a disease at all?

Edit: If the disease itself is legit, what would you call it?

Comment: Well, that would mean 'inflammation of the airconditioning'. Your guess is as good as mine about what it might refer to. Body parts hotter than A/C? Air conditioned to be hotter than outside? Failure of A/C altogether?

Comment: Koreans believe that [sleeping in a closed room with a fan blowing can kill you](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fan_death). *Spoiler*: no one else does.

Answer (score 3):

The *-itis* suffix is sometimes used [informally](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/-itis) make up a name for something that has perceived [disease like](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/-itis) qualities.

In some cases the speaker may be joking or simply using the term to make a point. In other cases the speaker may believe that they are describing a genuine malady but lacks a better or "official" word to describe it.

While medically *-itis* denotes inflammation, in cases such as the example given it should be taken to mean the problem (i.e. disease) is caused by or related to the word being modified.

In other words, the term *air-conditioningitis* is not in common usage by native speakers, but the manner in which it is constructed is not uncommon. As to the condition itself, I have no idea of it's a real thing and the name given sounds as good as any to me.

Comment: @medica I think that is matthew's point, that this is a jokey, made-up word. OP's article puts "air-conditioningits" in inverted commas (first use) to acknowledge that it is not a real medical term. The symptoms described may be real but as it's a recent phenomenon there is no single, official medical word for the condition.

Comment: Wiktionary has: Etymology
From NL -itis, from AG -ῖτις (-îtis, “pertaining to”). The feminine form of adjectival suffix -ίτης (-ítēs) because it was used with the feminine noun νόσος (nósos, “disease”), particularly with ἀρθρῖτις (νόσος) (arthrîtis (nósos), “disease of the joints”) (one of the earliest English borrowings from which the suffix was extracted and abstracted). Humorous sense by generalization. (pathology) Suffix denoting diseases characterized by inflammation, itself often caused by an infection.
(humorous) Used to form the names of various fictitious afflictions or diseases.

Answer (score 1):

It's a silly made up phrase.

As @John Lawler stated, *-itis* is the ending indicating inflammation. Arthritis means inflamed joints. Appendicitis means inflamed appendix. Phlebitis means inflamed veins.

Air-conditioningitis would mean the air conditioner was inflammed, which is not exactly possible, as it's not a biological unit. It could be *in flames*, but that would be something different.

Don't believe everything you read on the internet. I'm not saying the entire article is wrong (I didn't read it all), but the title is akin to someone being injured by hail and calling it *hailitis*.

Comment: I've skimmed through the article and I don't think the term is used in the article to mean that the air conditioner itself is inflamed. On the contrary, the term is used to describe a disease, caused by exposure to a/c, whose symptoms include "cold-like symptoms, chronic fatigue, headaches and digestive disorders." Also, I notice that the author is a professor and medical doctor. So, there might very well be some sort of truth to the disease, despite its "made up" name. If the disease itself is not made up, what would you call it?

Comment: I am also a doctor, and I guarantee you, there is no such "disease"; the fact that this terminology is used should tell you something about the quality of it's information. Nor would I call exposure to low-humidity air *a disease*. You asked a question about English here.

Comment: I've only ever heard of it as _air-conditionitis_ (one syllable less), and only as a general joking term for when you get the sniffles and a cough because you're not used to sleeping in a glacially air-conditioned room.

Comment: _Hailitis_ doesn't exist? I thought that's what Caesar died of :-0